# Paperclip gem not uploading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Ok so I have searched around a lot for an answer to this and I think I am just missing something obvious but I'm new to RoR so bear with me.

I'm using Paperclip and the gem installed fine. I have been following the tutorial on railscasts at http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?autoplay=true and I have followed the instructions perfectly but it doesn't work.

I'm guessing it is because of a different version of rails and something to do with strong parameters? I'm looking to upload a picture for a recipe upload. The database migrations have worked as I have checked and all relevant columns are present.

All of  the below are included:

#### recipe.rb file:

```
 has_attached_file :image
```

#### _recipe_form.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "My Recipe" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Write a description..." %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

#### recipe_controller.rb file:

```
def create
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save
    flash[:success] = "Recipe Created!"
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    @feed_items = []
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

### edit:

Added

#### Migrations

```
class AddAttachmentImageToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :recipes do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :recipes, :image
  end
end
```

#### Call to recipe

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error? In production or locally? Give some context.

Comment: Apologies @SimoneCarletti, No I am able to fill in the form, select an image and submit. The form still works and adds to the database however the image file is never uploaded and if I check the database there is no information in the image columns.

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding paperclip?

Comment: Yup i've tried that. DO you know if the use of paperclip has changed at all since rails 4?

Comment: Can you add your recipe_params method and your migrations?

Comment: @antox just added the migrations and I am not 100% if I added the recipe_params method. Do tell me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please raise(recipe_params.inspect). I want to see what do you actually pass to the controller. Also You are on Rails 4, correct? Thanks

Comment: @MikeHolford Report the recipe_params method

Comment: @antox Thanks for your help, I managed to inspect the params and the answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help. I managed to get some outside help on this. It was a simple fix and one I am sure you would have spotted if I had shown the params!

I forgot to add in :image to my params as below

```
params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :description, :live, :image)
```

All fixed. thank you!